# Angular 9 Ivy - Generic type 'ɵɵFactoryDef' requires 2 type argument(s)

Tags: angular, ivy, angular9

Looks like Angular Ivy not ready yet. I'm trying to build my project using ivy which is the main idea for Angular 9. Many of libraries are not compatible with this feature, one of these library is `@angular/flex-layout`. Material and service-worker have the same problem as well.

After using `ng build --prod --aot -c=production` script to build my project I got:

```
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/core/typings/media-trigger/media-trigger.d.ts:71:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵFactoryDef' requires 2 type argument(s).

71     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<MediaTrigger>;
                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/extended/typings/show-hide/show-hide.d.ts:18:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵFactoryDef' requires 2 type argument(s).

18     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<ShowHideStyleBuilder>;
                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/extended/typings/show-hide/show-hide.d.ts:49:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵFactoryDef' requires 2 type argument(s).

49     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<ShowHideDirective>;
```

The error longer than what I wrote above, I took my time to have a good search for this issue, nothing on the table but disabling ivy which is not a good option.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Fortunately, Angular 9.1 has been released and the problem solved. After upgrading to 9.1 (by running `ng update @angular/cli @angular/core`) I deleted my node_modules and reinstall it again. Then I upgraded my typescript from `3.7.5` to `3.8.3`. Now the ngcc is working fine and I have no errors after building.

For more info: [Angular Version 9.1](https://blog.angular.io/version-9-1-of-angular-now-available-typescript-3-8-faster-builds-and-more-eb292f989428)

Comment: what is your complete postinstall command? is it only `"postinstall":"ngcc"`??

Comment: @harishr Yes it is "ngcc", If you are upgrading don't use entry point. Just stay with ngcc

Comment: I am still facing the issue... had to revert to 9.0.5 to resolve the issue

Comment: @harishr Did you remove your `node_modules` and reinstall it again? What is exactly your error?

Comment: yes, I did that... i updated typescript n all other packages. deleted node_modules and resinstalled everything, but still getting exactly the same error which you mentioned in your question. Do i need to clear global cache?

Comment: @harishr Yes try to clear cache and make sure your package should be latest. My version is `"@angular/flex-layout": "^9.0.0-beta.29"`

Comment: Yes, removing node_modules and `npm cache verify` did the trick for me

Answer (score 2):

You might get the below error by using `ng update @angular/cli @angular/core`

> Error: Repository is not clean. Please commit or stash any changes before updating.

Use command

```
ng update @angular/cli @angular/core --allow-dirty
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case was to remove node_modules folder completely and run an ***npm install***
after that it works

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me. I had imported @angular/cdk/scrolling & had same issue!