# Angular 10 errors - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵFactoryDef' requires 1 type argument(s)

Tags: angular

After upgrading to angular 10.0, I keep getting this error below on ng serve:

ERROR in ../stocks/node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts:256:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵFactoryDef' requires 1 type argument(s).

256     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<ApplicationInitStatus, [{ optional: true; }]>;
../stocks/node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts:439:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵFactoryDef' requires 1 type argument(s).
439     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<ApplicationRef, never>;

../stocks/node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts:785:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵFactoryDef' requires 1 type argument(s).
785     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<Compiler, never>;

I have tried removing the "node_modules" folder, npm cache clean --force and npm install again. I still get this error.

My dependencies in package.json below:

"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "~10.0.0",
"@angular/common": "~10.0.0",
"@angular/compiler": "~10.0.0",
"@angular/core": "~10.0.0",
"@angular/forms": "~10.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~10.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.0.0",
"@angular/router": "~10.0.0",
"rxjs": "~6.5.5",
"tslib": "^2.0.0",
"zone.js": "~0.10.3"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1000.0",
"@angular/cli": "~10.0.0",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.0.0",
"@types/node": "^12.11.1",
"@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
"@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
"codelyzer": "^6.0.0-next.1",
"jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
"karma": "~5.0.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
"karma-jasmine": "~3.3.0",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
"protractor": "~7.0.0",
"ts-node": "~8.3.0",
"tslint": "~6.1.0",
"typescript": "~3.9.5"
}

How to get rid of this error?

Comment: maybe you can try this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60898133/angular-9-ivy-generic-type-%C9%B5%C9%B5factorydef-requires-2-type-arguments

 removing node_modules and `npm cache verify` and reinstall it again

Comment: I have tried "npm cache verify" as well. It's the same error again.